# aws-amplify Single login for multiple applications

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have multiple applications where the user logins via a cognito login. Currently they have to login at each application with the same cred. All apps live at the same domain. I need to allow the user to login to one location and when they attempt to access a new application verify their token. If valid, they've logged into another app, otherwise they haven't logged in yet.

tl;dr

- two applications: `appA` and `appB` on the same domain
  (client.mysite.com/appname)
- currently user logs into `appA` and
  `appB` separately with the same login cred
- I want user to log into
  `appA` then they try to access `appB` they are verified and let in

They all have the same userpool and identity pool. I'm calling `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. From my understanding if they he same UP and IP ids and on the same domain it should allow access.

How do I authenticate at the second app without an actual login?

Platform: Angular 15

Libraries: @aws-amplify/ui-angular: 4 aws-amplify: 5

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if your apps are on the same domain you can use cookies to store and share authentication information across applications.

After a user is logged in, you can set cookies with user info (*don't forget to use `Secure` attribute with your `Domain` and `SameSite=None` as an option. You can read more about how to work with cookies on the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies*)

After that, in your other apps, you will be able to read the data from the cookies and there will be everything that you need to treat your user as logged in.